# Loading data with bootstrapTable fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic-data

I am new to bootstrap and simply trying to replicate several examples of loading data into a bootstrap table, but my data does not show up.  Here is the html from jsfiddle

```
<table class="table" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="id">Item ID</th>
      <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
      <th data-field="price">Item Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
var $table = $('#table');
var mydata = [{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "test0",
  "price": "$0"
}];

$(function() {
  $('#table').bootstrapTable(
    data: mydata)
  );
});
```

The header shows up fine, but the data does not.  [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/lindermm/9g7c34rb/) is a link to the jsFiddle.

Comment: bootstrap datatable: https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/
https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bootstrapTable does not come with bootstrap. you need to include it.

https://jsfiddle.net/9g7c34rb/1/

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified Locales -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.11.1/locale/bootstrap-table-zh-CN.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Works great.  Hope the post helps others.